# Comparison of explaned variances in PCA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, pca

I computed a PCA and am interestet in the *explained variance* of the first unrotated component. The same procedure was used in a previous study.

**Question:** How do I test whether the two explaned variance ("mine" and the one from the previous study) differ significantly?

Note: Procedure and input variables are the same, samples are independent and differ in size.

Comment: - Some samples could don't come from the same distribution
- In some sample could exist lacks of data
- Did you remember about scale variables before start of PCA?

Comment: Suppose yours explains more variance than the previous one, then what does it mean? I do not think it mean that your PCA is better than previous PCA.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "explained variance" is a proportion, you could do a test of the differences in the proportions. For instance, R has the `prop.test` function.

Why you are interested in this is a good question; what do you hope to do if they are significantly different? What about if they are not?

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.

Comment: I added some more.